# Replace unwanted special characters from a string, retain special characters between two numerical

Tags: python, regex, nlp

Hi I am working on one NLP project, where I need to identify entities / organization names from the text. However, the words in string are concatenated with (_  : ,) characters as shown below:

```
RING_LECO:108_.250X.436X.093V_772_520
```

I would want to clean the string as below:

```
Ring Leco 108 .250X.436X.093V 772_520
```

We have removed special characters between two words (A-Z:A-Z,A-Z:0-9) but retained _ symbol between 772 and 520.

Is there any way that I could do this?

Comment: Your desired output string has different casing, has a `0` before the `.250` that wasn't there before, a `0` after the `X` in `.250X`, and other differences. What are the rules for that? Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've edited the desired string, I am sorry for the mistake. I am not able to move forward on this. hence, needed help!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - so, the change from "RING_LECO" to "Ring Leco" is intentional?

Comment: Yes. It is intentional to make first letter Uppercase in every word. But it is optional any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
(?<=\D)[_:,]|[_:,](?=\D)
```

`\D` represents a non-digit character, so the pattern matches special characters (`_:,`) that have a non-digit character on at least one side.

```
str = 'RING_LECO:108_.250X.436X.093V_772_520'
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\D)[_:,]|[_:,](?=\D)')
print(pattern.sub(' ', str))
```

Output:

```
RING LECO 108 .250X.436X.093V 772_520
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick:

```
_([^0-9]?<=)|(?=[^0-9])_
```

In English: "either before or after the underscore is not a number"

?<= means that whatever **precedes** is the group to capture

?= means that whatever **follows** is the group to capture